# Insert a special html after button with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i Insert a html after my button with jquery ? can i use insertAfter() function ? if yes i want like this :

```
$(widget/mytemp.html).insertAfter( "#foo" );
```

because my html file is another place!

Comment: What do you mean your "HTML file is another place" ?

Comment: another place from my JS file !

Comment: ya ... always we pass text or tag to `insertAfter();` function i want pass a html file !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

Use it to load html in a div after your button.

**html**

```
<button id="foo">My Button</button>
<div id="area"></div>
```

**js**

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
    $("#area").load("path_to_html");
});
```

Comment: thanks .... i think about this ! so i want this happen after click ! how can i do this ? i must use `insertAfter` ?

Comment: thanks but why it load all of my home page ? my separate html that i want to load it is short ! just shows somthing !

Comment: what do you mean? do you want a specific portion of the html page?

Comment: no ! i have a html file that show some info of user ! that i want show them after click ! now after your code that i try it later again ! it load all the main page ?

Comment: `PermissionButton.unbind('click').click(function(event){Vote.permission(PermissionButton);$("#area").load("widgets/user_card2.html");});`
so when i copy my html in that `div` i see excepted result !!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58291/discussion-between-thecbuilder-and-kasra).